# Merging 2 Xcode projects - two AppDelegates causing errors

Tags: iphone, xcode, merge, projects

I have two Xcode iPhone projects I want to merge.  Both have viewcontrollers, xibs and appdelegates.

I have merged them but have over a dozen fatal errors, largely about one of the appdelegates.

I went into info.plist and changed the main nib from the first project to the second but am still getting the errors about the second project's appdelegate.

Not sure how to resolve this ... copy everything from the second AD over to the first AD?

Brooks

Comment: If you're using a MainWindow.xib: Make sure that inside that the right AppDelegate is being used  if you're not: Make sure the right one is used in main.m

Answer (score 0):

Look in the settings for the targets, you should be able to specify their app delegates somewhere there, I dont quite remember where, dont have my mac infront of me, but when im there ill check it  out and post an edit.